# Is it possible to add bookmarks to a PDF document with Acrobat Reader?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, bookmarks, adobe-reader

I've been trying to bookmark several pages of a PDF file using Acrobat Reader, and while the Bookmarks tab is available, it is disabled:

[image: Bookmarks tab]

Is it possible to bookmark pages using Acrobat Reader?

Comment: Not as far as I know having used both products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Adobe would rather one license the full application to edit a PDF document, there are other, free, applications that *do* let one add bookmarks, annotations, comments, "sticky notes", and even edit text (though text editing is often an extra "freemium" feature), such as [PDF-XChange Editor](https://pdf-xchange.eu/pdf-xchange-editor/) and [Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader), shown below.

[image: PDF-XChange Editor Bookmark]

[image: Sumatra PDF Favorite]

You did not specify the operating system in the question, but the above applications, though native to Windows OS, run quite well on Linux under *wine*.

Note that not all PDF documents can be annotated -- if one is write protected, or entirely images, annotation may be grayed out.